# Group XML using XSLT

Tags: xslt-1.0

I'm trying to create a header detail XML document, set from another xml.

Source xml document:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <col1>H</col1>
        <col2>header1</col2>
    </item>
    <item>
        <col1>D</col1>
        <col2>detail1.1</col2>
    </item>
    <item>
        <col1>D</col1>
        <col2>detail1.2</col2>
    </item>
    <item>
        <col1>H</col1>
        <col2>header2</col2>
    </item>
    <item>
        <col1>D</col1>
        <col2>detail2.1</col2>
    </item>
    <item>
        <col1>D</col1>
        <col2>detail2.2</col2>
    </item>
    <item>
        <col1>D</col1>
        <col2>detail2.3</col2>
    </item>
</items>
```

Desired Output:

```
<xml>
    <transaction>
        <items>
            <item>
                <col1>H</col1>
                <col2>header1</col2>
            </item>
            <item>
                <col1>D</col1>
                <col2>detail1.1</col2>
            </item>
            <item>
                <col1>D</col1>
                <col2>detail1.2</col2>
            </item>
        </items>
    </transaction>
    <transaction>
        <items>
            <item>
                <col1>H</col1>
                <col2>header2</col2>
            </item>
            <item>
                <col1>D</col1>
                <col2>detail2.1</col2>
            </item>
            <item>
                <col1>D</col1>
                <col2>detail2.2</col2>
            </item>
            <item>
                <col1>D</col1>
                <col2>detail2.3</col2>
            </item>
        </items>
    </transaction>
</xml>
```

My attempted XSLT:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/ | node() | @* | comment() | processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="item[col1='H']">
        <transaction>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </transaction>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kItemByCol2Num" match="item[starts-with(col2, 'detail')]"
  use="substring-before(substring-after(col2, 'detail'), '.')"/>

 <xsl:key name="kItemByCol2Num" match="item[starts-with(col2, 'header')]"
  use="substring-after(col2, 'header')"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "item
   [starts-with(col2, 'header')
  and
    generate-id()
   =
    generate-id(key('kItemByCol2Num', substring-after(col2, 'header'))[1])
   ]">
  <transaction>
    <xsl:copy-of select="key('kItemByCol2Num', substring-after(col2, 'header'))"/>
  </transaction>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="item"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<items>
    <item>
        <col1>H</col1>
        <col2>header1</col2>
    </item>
    <item>
        <col1>D</col1>
        <col2>detail1.1</col2>
    </item>
    <item>
        <col1>D</col1>
        <col2>detail1.2</col2>
    </item>
    <item>
        <col1>H</col1>
        <col2>header2</col2>
    </item>
    <item>
        <col1>D</col1>
        <col2>detail2.1</col2>
    </item>
    <item>
        <col1>D</col1>
        <col2>detail2.2</col2>
    </item>
    <item>
        <col1>D</col1>
        <col2>detail2.3</col2>
    </item>
</items>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<items>
   <transaction>
      <item>
         <col1>H</col1>
         <col2>header1</col2>
      </item>
      <item>
         <col1>D</col1>
         <col2>detail1.1</col2>
      </item>
      <item>
         <col1>D</col1>
         <col2>detail1.2</col2>
      </item>
   </transaction>
   <transaction>
      <item>
         <col1>H</col1>
         <col2>header2</col2>
      </item>
      <item>
         <col1>D</col1>
         <col2>detail2.1</col2>
      </item>
      <item>
         <col1>D</col1>
         <col2>detail2.2</col2>
      </item>
      <item>
         <col1>D</col1>
         <col2>detail2.3</col2>
      </item>
   </transaction>
</items>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Proper use of the Muenchian method for grouping.
2. Proper use of keys.

Comment: It works for the provided xml however my requirement is to group on col1. I made up the sample xml with col2='header' and 'detail' just so the output sets would be distinguishable. I'm trying with the xslt you provided, but since I'm not familiar with the key() I'm still not getting the desired output. My original xml has different values on col2 and actually it has more than 20 columns.

Comment: @gangt, THe provided "desired output" *isn't* grouped by `col1` !!! If you want, you may ask a new question -- the question in its current form is completely answered. If you keep specifying in the new questions data that isn't what you actually have, no wonder -- the answers would be rather unusable.